# corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

[What's wrong with that code! it doesn't run?

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    major VARCHAR(20),
);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ')' at line 5

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of that trailing comma after `VARCHAR(20)`.